# Script for Graceful Shutdown for Gridgain Ignite Webconsole

Tags: ignite, gridgain

As mentioned in ignite documentation, I am starting the ignite webconsole and web agent using the below scripts. We have 3 ignite clusters to monitor (3 web agents):

1. ./gridgain-web-console-linux --server:port 3000
2. ./ignite-web-agent.sh

What is the script to gracefully shutdown the ignite webconsole and webagent components. 
At present, I am manually killing the respective process ids. 
Need to schedule the startup and shutdown of ignite webconsole  on the server.

Comment: I think that sending `HUP` signal should work reasonably well.

Comment: Thanks Alamar. Can you please send a sample. Also, I have observed that the webconsole webagent, starts some additional webconsole processes internally. just curious, how can  these internal processes can also be stopped.

Answer (score 0):

If Web Console is started from console, you can just press Ctrl-C to terminate it.

If it is detached or needed to be killed automatically, you can use `kill <pid>`.

Comment: Needed to configure and schedule  the start and stop on crontab. Thanks anyways. I have written a manual shell script to start and kill the respective process pids of webconsole.